# Select multiple values in cognos dropdown list

Tags: drop-down-menu, cognos

I have a scenario like in my report I have value prompt, my client requirement is, they want to select multiple values with drop-down list, how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by setting the prompt object to multi select and ensuring the filter that uses it has an in clause instead of an equals.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple value selection from a drop down Value prompt, only checkbox (personal favourite) or a listbox.
To enable this, change the Value prompt propertie "Multiselect" to "Yes" and in the filter that uses the Value prompt paramatere, make sure its either in or not in or any other operator that accepts multiple inputs.

Comment: What if I want that drop-down list for filtering of the website then there I need to use the checkbox again but what about that selection under the drop-down list